# ScalaJS facades with JS and application data

Tags: scala.js

I'm attempting to write a facade for a jQuery plugin (https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete).  In includes some callbacks that pass an object I've modelled as:

```
@js.native
trait AutocompleteSuggestion extends js.Object {
  val value: String = js.native
  val data : js.Any = js.native
}
```

The library needs to access `value`;  `data` is for my use.  I create the object, feed it to the library, and it gives it back to me as the argument to a callback.

The best I've been able to do for creating these objects is

```
object AutocompleteSuggestion {
  def apply[T](value: String, data: T) = {
    literal(value = value, data = data.asInstanceOf[js.Any]).asInstanceOf[AutocompleteSuggestion]
  }
}
```

Callbacks that are passed one of these objects often end up looking like

```
def onSelect(suggestion: AutocompleteSuggestion): Unit = {
  val cb = suggestion.data.asInstanceOf[CourseBasic]
  // do something with the data
}
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this?  In particular it feels like I'm doing a lot of casting.  I don't see that in the examples at https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html -- but those examples also studiously avoid using anything but primitive types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following. Basically it boils down to typing your `AutocompleteSuggestion` better by giving a type parameter for the type of `data`. In addition, we make it an `@ScalaJSDefined` trait instead of `@js.native` (as most JS traits should be anyway) so that we can instantiate it in a type-safe way:

```scala
import js.annotation._

@ScalaJSDefined
trait AutocompleteSuggestion[T] extends js.Object {
  val value: String
  val data: T
}

object AutocompleteSuggestion {
  def apply[T](value0: String, data0: T): AutocompleteSuggestion[T] = {
    new AutocompleteSuggestion[T] {
      val value: String = value0
      val data: T = data0
    }
  }
}

def onSelect(suggestion: AutocompleteSuggestion[CourseBasic]): Unit = {
  val cb = suggestion.data
  // do something with the data
}
```

Aaand, not a single cast :)

Comment: Beautiful.  To my chagrin, I've ignored ScalaJSDefined.  Thanks for the push to go read the documentation again.